# VideoChat signalling server- Android

Tags: android, webrtc, kurento

Trying to make a video chat app, unable to figure out the signalling server. I do not wanna create my own signalling server, what to do?
Do not wanna user pubnub webrtc.
Is there any signalling server available. Can i do real-time video chat with webrtc without the custom signalling server.
Which are available signalling servers for android application.

Tried kurento, but in docs i can see even they are creating a signalling server using java spring boot framework.

[kurento-java-one-one-video-chat](http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/java/tutorial-one2one.html)

Comment: Websockets with node js is sufficient to create a signalling server

Comment: @me_ what if i do not wanna create my own signalling server ?

Comment: This provides a stun and turn server api...  depending on your usage level it can be free... https://xirsys.com/easyrtc/

Comment: Have you looked into using TokBox? http://tokbox.com/

They provide a whole WebRTC platform including TURN/STUN servers, signalling servers, Media Server/SFU and even easier to use client SDK for Android. So no need to setup all that server infrastructure.  (Disclosure I work at TokBox)

Comment: yeah, i tried tokbox, works great.